# wpf: left button click is not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent

I newly in WPF and when I learn the material I faced with strange issue.

I build a button, contain layers with text block and I want to recognize where the user click on the button itself, on 'first', 'second, or 'third' (I output a message).

[image]

All works fine except the button not raise an event when the user clicks with left button (just with middle or right button).

so my question: Why I not received a message box when I press on the button itself with left mouse button (and I receive the msg box with other mouse buttons) ?

**XAML:**

```
<Button Margin="145,152,144,102" Padding="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseDown="Button_MouseDown" Height="57" Width="214">
    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" MouseDown="TextBlockFirst_MouseDown" >First  </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="24"   MouseDown="TextBlockSecond_MouseDown">Second </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" FontSize="24"  MouseDown="TextBlockThird_MouseDown" >Third  </TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</Button>
```

**Code:**

```
private void TextBlockFirst_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You click on first");
}

private void TextBlockSecond_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You click on second");
}

private void TextBlockThird_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You click on third");
}

private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // This event not working good
    // only middle & right mouse buttons are recognized
    MessageBox.Show("You click on the button");
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**`MouseDown`** event is a **`bubbling event`** which bubbles from its originator to its root parent. But **`Click`** event eat up the **`MouseDown`** event and doesn't allow the event from bubbling upto Button.

You can use **`PreviewMouseDown`** event which is a **`tunnelling event`** which tunnels from root to its originator. So button will first get this event and then subsequent textBlock.

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_MouseDown">
   .......
</Button>
```

Refer to the snapshot below for the clear picture:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Hook only `PreviewMouseDown` event on button and remove handlers from individual textBlocks. Check for `e.OrignialSource` to see if `TextBlock` is actual original source or button.

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You click on the button");
    }
    else
    {
        switch ((e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text)
        {
            case "First":
                MessageBox.Show("You click on first");
                break;
            case "Second":
                MessageBox.Show("You click on second");
                break;
            case "Third":
                MessageBox.Show("You click on third");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

*XAML*

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown" Height="57" Width="214">
    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="24">First</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="24">Second</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" FontSize="24">Third</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I try it and I getting only the button event (and not the text block event). If I change trigger to `PreviewMouseDown` also in the text-blocks I recieve two message box per click (I want only one msg and the true one..)

Comment: @AsfK : Hook only `PreviewMouseDown` event on button and not on TextBlock and check for `e.OriginalSource` in handler to see for originator of event.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work, because the first fires is an event at the `Button.Click`, and when it works, it conflicts with the events like: `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseDown`.

To make has worked this event, you need to define an `PreviewMouseDown` event, because it's a *`Tunnel`* event, this means that it will go down of the VisualTree hierarchy, therefore it is triggered before the Bubble events.

Also, as alternative, you can use the `Button.Click` event for Button.