# C# MouseButtonEventHandler not detecting left click?

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

For a homework project that's due all too soon, I need to make a simple wpf application game. I chose to make a Picross/nonogram game, and I want to make an event handler that makes an "X" appear in a button if I right click and a black square appear if I left click. I can do a left click if I just do btn.Click to point to a RoutedEventHandler, but it doesn't seem to have a way to detect right clicks that way so I tried instead to have MouseDown point to a MouseButtonEventHandler. When I do this, it only detects right clicks and never left clicks though. How do I make an event handler that handles both?

Here is what I have with my code at the moment:

```
      public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {

                    System.Windows.Controls.Button btn = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();

                    btn.Width = 60;

                    btn.Height = 60;

                    btn.Background = Brushes.White;

                    btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                    btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                    btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

                    btn.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(btn1_Click);


                    grdPuzzle.Children.Add(btn);
                    Grid.SetRow(btn, i);

                    Grid.SetColumn(btn, j);



                }




            }
```

```
        private void btn1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

        {

            System.Windows.Controls.Button btn2 = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;


            if (btn2.Background == Brushes.White)
            {
                btn2.Background = Brushes.Black;

            }
            else
                btn2.Background = Brushes.White;



        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if mouse button is left or right in wpf C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718317/how-can-i-check-if-mouse-button-is-left-or-right-in-wpf-c)

Comment: No, I've looked at that post already but even with following their advice it doesn't detect any left clicks for me

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can detect only right click using `MouseDown` event is because `MouseDown` event is a bubbling event which bubbles from its originator to its root parent. You can use `PreviewMouseDown` event which is a tunnelling event which tunnels from root to its originator.

Example of code that should meet your requirements:

Button:

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_MouseDown">Click me</Button>
```

Event:

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right click");
    }
    if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Left click");
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23040891/12315553)